# An inaccessible class. VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, oop, visual-studio-2010

I realy dont know what the problem is with VS2010. I created a class, and when I'm trying  create an exemplar of the class I get an error: "Error  xxx is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public string name;
    public int age;

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Person ps = new Person("Jack", 19);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the public keywork to the Person constructor:

```
public Person(string name, int age)
```

Comment: ideed this is a C++ habit to avoid "public"

Answer (score 6):

You need to make your constructor `public`:

```
public Person(string name, int age)
{
    ...
```

You may ask, why aren't constructors `public` by default?  What's the point of a class you can't instantiate via its constructor?  Well, it can be useful if you want a class that can only be instantiated via factory methods, eg.

```
public class Person
{
    public static Person makePerson(string name, int age)
    {
        ...
```

The factory method, being a member of the `Person` class, *can* access the non-`public` constructor.